# Save screenshot and share on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, libgdx

I want the user to click a button and it takes a screenshot if the screen and then starts the sharing process into Facebook.

This is how I take and process the screenshot:

```
private void saveScreenshot() {
    try{
        FileHandle fh;
        do{
            fh = new FileHandle(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath() + "stoneIMG" + counter++ + ".png");
        }while(fh.exists());
        Pixmap pixmap = getScreenshot(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
        System.out.println(fh.toString());
        Gdx.app.exit();
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}

private Pixmap getScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean yDown){
    final Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h);

    if(yDown) {
        ByteBuffer pixels = pixmap.getPixels();
        int numBytes = w * h * 4;
        byte[] lines = new byte[numBytes];
        int numBytesPerLine = w * 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            pixels.position((h - i - 1) * numBytesPerLine);
            pixels.get(lines, i * numBytesPerLine, numBytesPerLine);
        }

        pixels.clear();
        pixels.put(lines);
    }
    return pixmap;
}
```

and then:

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
    .setBitmap(image);
    .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
    .addPhoto(photo)
    .build();
```

To share it. But I can't figure out how to connect these two. I mean the screenshot saves a PNG image to some storage but I have no clue where. 
Anyone that got a idea?

Answer (score 0):

First, you take the screenshot:

```
saveScreenshot();
```

The file path is `Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath() + "stoneIMG" + counter + ".png"` (look at the `FileHandle` object). To load the file to a `Bitmap`, you can use the following code:

```
String filePath = Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath() + "stoneIMG" + counter + ".png";
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
```

Then you can send it using:

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
    .setBitmap(bitmap);
    .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
    .addPhoto(photo)
    .build();
```

Comment: Is that Libgdx code? Cause I get "BitmapFactory cannot be resolved to a type" on BitmapFactory? Otherwise, great explaining!

Comment: You need to write `import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;` at the beginning of the code

Comment: You used `SharePhoto` which is Android specific code AFAIK (so I thought you can simply write Android code). Have a look at this website how to add Android code: http://rotatingcanvas.com/writing-android-specific-code-in-libgdx/